# Editortemplate for List<ComplexType> not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to create an Editortemplate for a `List<Package>`.  I am fully qualifying the type in my Editortemplate view as such:

```
@model List<JYP.Business.ViewModels.Package>
```

When I try to reference Model within my Editortemplate view, I am getting a null reference which leads me to believe that the model isn't getting associated properly.  I had to use a `UIHint` in my ViewModel in order to have it use the Editortemplate at all.  My ViewModel contains a `List<Package> Packages` which is what I am trying to have my custom Editortemplate pick up.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Couldn't you simply specify it as @model JYP.Business.ViewModels.Package because @Html.EditorFor() will automatically iterate through the list of packages in the model and invoke your EditorTemplate for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rely on conventions:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<Package> Packages { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your main view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Packages)
```

and then you could define an editor template which will be automatically rendered for each element of the Packages collection:

```
@model JYP.Business.ViewModels.Package
...
```

By convention this editor template should be placed in the `~/Views/SomeController/EditorTemplates/Package.cshtml` or `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Package.cshtml`. Those are the 2 locations that ASP.NET MVC will look for it in that order.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement i understand that you don't want to use UIHint or any other way that say which template to use.

This may work for you.

```
public class PackageCollection : List<JYP.Business.ViewModels.Package>
    {
    }
```

Now In Main Model use

```
public class ModelTest{
public PackageCollection Items { get; set;}
public ModelTest(){
    Items = new PackageCollection();
}
}
```

Now create EditorTemplate with Name PackageCollection.cshtml or PackageCollection.ascx as per your ViewEngine.

**Another Solution**

Now if you do not wan't to use UIHint and above solution then you have to specify TemplateName in Editor For

```
Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Items , "yourtemplatename")
```

This works without creating packagecollection class.

Thanks.